# PyCurl. 'Can't pickle Curl object' error on Windows x64

Tags: python, curl, multiprocessing, pickle, pycurl

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import pycurl

class Bot(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)       
        self.c = pycurl.Curl() 

    def run(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    Bot().start()
```

This code works good on Ubuntu 13.04 x64, but fails on Windows 7 x64/Server 2008 x64. I use pyCurl 7.19.0 and Python 2.7.
The error is:

```
Z:\bot>python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 74, in <module>
    Bot().start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 104, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 244, in __init__
    dump(process_obj, to_child, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 167, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 313, in save
    (t.__name__, obj))
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle 'Curl' object: <pycurl.Curl object at 0x00000
00002360478>

Z:\bot>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 347, in main
    self = load(from_parent)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

Why this happens?

Comment: Although `pycurl` builds easily for me on linux, I'm having a hard time getting it working on windows;  The prebuilt windows installers stop at python2.5.  Is there a particular protocol you're trying to use that only `pycurl` supports?  There are many alternatives.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy no, i was going to use it for a little speed advantage.

Comment: Hmm... just about anything you could possibly do with `libcurl` will be IO bound, are you using it to make connections to the local host?

Comment: @TokenMacGuy No. But i find it faster than urllib2. And unlike urrllib2 pycurl respects provided timeouts.

Comment: have you tried the fine [`requests`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) library?

Comment: @TokenMacGuy no, i use Grab instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On posix systems, `multiprocessing` works by using the `fork()` syscall, which clones the running process, and all of its state (including things like instances of complex classes, such as `pycurl.Curl`).

Windows does not have `fork()`, or anything like it, so `multiprocessing` fires up a new python interpreter for each child process, with a special stub function that listens to the parent process and recreates the state so that it looks much like it would had `fork()` been used.  The key technique used by `multiprocessing` for this is that it recreates each object in the child process, from the parent process, as they are used.  This works by converting the objects to a bytecode representation (using the `pickle` module), sending them over a pipe to the child, and converting them back to python objects once there.

For most kinds of python objects, this works perfectly, and is transparent to you.  There are a number of obvious kinds of things where this cannot possibly work; open files cannot be passed around in this way; nor can the state of non-python library objects, which don't know anything about the `pickle` system.  Unfortunately, `pycurl` is a bit of both of these things.